# Why does programmatically switching layers in openlayers introduce this strange behaviour?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, openlayers

I want to switch layers programmatically when a control button is clicked.

When I do this, the map stops working correctly, it becomes really buggy.
To be more precise, the drawing handlers are not working correctly at all after that.

Can anyone tell me how to switch between layers and control them programmatically and why is this not working?

Here is the code:

```
find_control(editing_toolbar_polygon.getControlsByClass(new RegExp(".*DrawFeature")),"Point").events.register("activate",null,function(e){
    map.removeControl(editing_toolbar_polygon);
    polygon_layer.setVisibility(false);
    vectors.setVisibility(true);
    map.addControl(editing_toolbar_vector);
});
```

This:

```
find_control(editing_toolbar_polygon.getControlsByClass(new RegExp(".*DrawFeature")),"Point")
```

just returns a control to which I set a call back function on `activate`.

Answer (score 2):

To switch map layers you should use Map's method `setBaseLayer`. See [documentation](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.setBaseLayer).

Answer (score 2):

To change the layer You could use folowing snippet :

```
map.setBaseLayer(map.layers[0]);
```

Or You could find the layer by name with :

```
map.getLayersByName(layerName);
```